# Are Rouché's theorem and the maximum modulus principle equivalent?

Tags: complex-analysis

The [symmetric version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem#Symmetric_version) of the Rouché's theorem implies the [maximum modulus principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle) as you can read below. I wonder if the converse is true.

Does the maximum modulus principle imply the symmetric version of Rouché's theorem?

$\underline{Symmetric\ version\ of\ Rouché\ theorem \Rightarrow maximum\ modulus\ principle.}$

Suppose $|f(z_0)|\geq|f(z)|$ for every $z\in D$, where $D$ is a open ball cointaining $z_0$ and $f$ is holomorphic on $D$.

If $f(z)-f(z_0)\neq 0$ on $D$ then, by the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem), there is a closed ball $B$ contained in $D$ such that

1. $z_0$ belongs to the interior of $B$
2. $|f(z)-f(z_0)|>0$ for every $z\in  B\setminus\{z_0\}$.

Define $g(z)=f(z_0)$ and $h(z)=f(z)-f(z_0)$.  So for every $z\in \partial B$ $$|g(z)+h(z)|=|f(z)|<|f(z_0)|+|f(z)-f(z_0)|=|g(z)|+|h(z)|.$$

By Rouché's theorem, $g(z)$ and $h(z)$ have the same number of zeros in the interior of $B$, but $h(z)$ has only one $(z_0)$ and $g(z)$ has none if $f(z_0)\neq 0$ or infinitely many if $f(z_0)=0$.

So $f(z)-f(z_0)=0$ on $D$.

Comment: Harmonic functions satisfy maximum modulus but Rouche depends on the argument principle which holds in more generality than for holomorphic functions true, but not in that much generality, so the answer is no, maximum modulus by itself is not enough; your proof btw is not quite correct but close enough

Comment: @Conrad Where did I make the mistake?

Comment: Maybe I misread the proof and thought that you claimed that either one has strict inequality on some ball or one has equality everywhere which needs the identity theorem, but now looking back I see you justified the step so I agree with it;